# How to get UN Comtrade data using Python?

Tags: python, json, api

I need to get data from the [UN Comtrade](https://comtrade.un.org/) using a call from python, but when I make that I get an error. However, if I do the same in R, I obtain a dictionary. I don't understand why this happens.

My Python code:

```
import requests
url='http://comtrade.un.org/data/api/get?max=500&type=C&freq=A&px=HS&ps=2018&r=152&p=all&rg=all&cc=851712'
un_data=requests.get(url)
print(un_data.content)
```

My R code:

```
install.package(jsonlite)
library(jsonlite)
un_data<-fromJSON('http://comtrade.un.org/data/api/get?max=500&type=C&freq=A&px=HS&ps=2018&r=152&p=all&rg=all&cc=851712')
View(un_data)
```

In my Python code, I get the following error:

> An error has occurred, please contact comtrade@un.org

However, using the R code I get a list with the data. I would like to obtain the same result that I get in R but in Python.

Answer (score 2):

There is a slight malformation in your request URL. Instead of your base url set as `http://comtrade.un.org/api/data/get`, it should be `http://comtrade.un.org/api/get`.

This may have to do with the transition from the Comtrade API from the old legacy version to the new one, though I'm not sure. In any case, you can test API calls here: [UN Comtrade Swagger UI](https://comtrade.un.org/api/swagger/ui/index#!/Data/Data_GetData)

Here's a working version of your reprex:

```
import requests
url='https://comtrade.un.org/api/get?max=500&type=C&freq=A&px=HS&ps=2018&r=152&p=all&rg=all&cc=851712'
un_data=requests.get(url)
print(un_data.content)
```